# Remove Control from Window in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, window

How can I remove a control from a window in WPF? `RemoveLogicalChild` only removes it as a logical child, but leaves it still visible.

Comment: how you are adding controls inside a window ? are u using Grid, StackPanel or Window.Content?

Comment: I'm using the Windows `AddChild` function

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Every element in the visual tree is either the root of the tree, like a `Window`, or a child of another element.  Ideally you would know which element is the parent of the element you are trying to remove and what type of `FrameworkElement` it is.

For example, if you have a `Canvas` and many children and you have a `Rectangle` that was previously added to the `Canvas`, you can remove it from the visual tree by removing it from the `Canvas` like this:

```
canvas.Children.Remove(control);
```

But if you don't **know** who the parent of the control is, you can use the [VisualTreeHelper.GetParent Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getparent.aspx) to find out:

```
DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(control);
```

The problem you now face is `parent` is a `DependencyObject` and while it is probably also a `FrameworkElement`, you don't know **which** kind of element it is.  This is important because how you remove the child depends on the type.  If the parent is a `Button`, then you just clear the `Content` property.  If the parent is a `Canvas`, you have to use `Children.Remove`.

In general, you can handle the most common cases by checking whether the item is a `Panel` and then remove from its children, otherwise if it is a `ContentControl` (like a `Window`) then set its `Content` property to `null`.  But this isn't foolproof; there are other cases.

You also have to be careful not to remove something that is expanded from a template because that is not a static content you can modify at will.  If you added the control or existed in static XAML, you can safely remove it.

Answer (score 0):

To check the parent type , You can also use the GetType Method adding toString Method and compare.
For example ,  the string "System.Windows.Controls.Canvas" will be returned when  the parent Object is a canvas

Comment: I'm not sure how checking the parent type through this method will help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to remove a child from ,in this case, a canvas.

```
private void RemoveControl()
{
   name = myUserControl.GetValue(NameProperty).ToString();               
   myCanvas.Children.Remove(myUserControl);
   NameScope.GetNameScope(this).UnregisterName(name);
}
```