# Does a collapsed control still take up memory?

Tags: c#, wpf, memory, controls, visibility

G'day folks

This is probably an easy one for you lot, but i'm curious...

If you hide a say for example a stackpanel using visibility.collapsed, does it remove it from memory?

if not, what would be the best and/or easiest way to remove say a stackpanel from memory, but be able to show it again easily?

I do understand i could just recreate the SP in the code-behind, but i'm wondering if there is an easy way?

I have thought of making the SP an usercontrol, or did i just answer my own question?

Edit:

Seems I did answer my own question, thanks Ben Voigt. And Now I know how to remove a child control thanks to Somesh Mukherjee, so it seems I can use both answers :)

Comment: When you say "show it again easily", do you mean it should remember any changes you or the user have made to its contents?  That requires memory.

Comment: I mean like for example adding it like SP.Add or something similar without having to redefine what the SP was (basically just showing a copy of how it was first defined)

Comment: Using a user control should help you there, since then you can call its constructor and add it back into the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't get removed from memory. You can use the remove method on canvas to remove it.

[Remove Control from Window in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501592/remove-control-from-window-in-wpf)