# How to remove a control from window programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a window with a button in it, and I need to remove it OR not depending on the argument passed to the window:

```
    public MainWindow(bool removeControl)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (removeControl)
        {
            //code to remove the button
        }
    }
```

In the XAML file I declare a normal button:

```
<Button Width="120" Height="25" Content="Click" Name="ClickButton"></Button>
```

I know this can be done by doing the reverse thing which means add the button depending of the Boolean parameter, but I need to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
mybutton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

...or if you really want it to be removed from the "logical tree"...then it all depends what "container"/parent that Button is in, in how you remove it.

- [Disconnecting an element from any/unspecified parent container in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317064/disconnecting-an-element-from-any-unspecified-parent-container-in-wpf)
- [Remove Control from Window in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501592/remove-control-from-window-in-wpf)
- http://joe-bq-wang.iteye.com/blog/1613370

Comment: Ah that's working, i tried to modify the isvisible property of the button but it doesn't work , thanks for the tiip